# Strange Direct3D memory behavior in Present()

Tags: c++, memory, directx, direct3d

So I am working on my own rendering engine and encountered some strange memory behavior.

When ever I call

```
IDXGISwapChain::Present(0, 0)
```

it increases my programs memory usage by the size of the vertices I rendered that frame.

I create a vertex buffer using this code:

```
ID3D10Buffer        *pVertexBuffer;
D3D10_BUFFER_DESC   desc;
desc.Usage          = D3D10_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
desc.ByteWidth      = stride * nNumVertices;
desc.BindFlags      = D3D10_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D10_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
desc.MiscFlags      = 0;
D3D10_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vData;
vData.pSysMem       = Vertices;

HRESULT hr = m_pDevice->CreateBuffer(&desc, &vData, &pVertexBuffer);
```

Draw it using

```
m_pDevice->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
m_pDevice->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);


m_pDevice->Draw(nNumVertices, 0);
```

And then Release it

```
pVertexBuffer->Release();
```

This throws the error

```
D3D10 INFO: ID3D10Device::IASetVertexBuffers: A currently bound VertexBuffer is being deleted; so naturally, will no longer be bound. [ STATE_SETTING INFO #31: IASETVERTEXBUFFERS_UNBINDDELETINGOBJECT]
```

But according to MSDN and other questions, this shouldn't be a problem.

Has anyone else experienced this before, or could give me a helping hand?

Edit1:

This happens a certain number of times, around 500, after this is stops using more memory.
If I then unload my mesh and reload it (so it has a different pointer), present() starts allocating more memory, the size of my mesh, for around 500 times. This goes on until my program runs out of memory.

One thing to add, the first time I call Present() it increases the used memory by the size of any texture I have bound, this includes the back buffer!

Comment: Does it still leak if you unbind before releasing? (http://www.gamedev.net/topic/522598-debug-utility-functions-with-dx10-drawing-a-line-box-etc/)

Comment: Does this happen on the first time you present? Or the second time?

Comment: This happens each time Present() is called, up until a certain size/amount. Right now it seems like this is ~500 times. Binding a null buffer fixed the INFO messages, but did not remove the memory problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting I have found what is happening here.
Each time a `ID3D10Buffer` is created using `CreateBuffer()`, `IDXGISwapChain::Present()` will  allocate 4 Kilobyte. For me, this happens 64 times per identical buffer and then it either stops, or releases the previously allocated memory.

I hope this might help someone else with this undocumented 'feature'

Comment: You should not be creating a new vertex buffer every frame. Creating resources is quite expensive, and you should reuse them. For static submission, you'd keep the buffer around for a long time. For dynamic submission, you'd use ``USAGE_DYNAMIC`` and update the VB using the Map ``WRITE_DISCARD`` pattern.

Comment: I fully agree with this, it's bad practice. However, it still should not leak memory when you are properly calling release. My guess is that it was creating debug records